# Elements of torsion n of an abelian group G

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I've been struggling forever with this problem. Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $G(n)$ denote the set of elements $g \in G$ such that $g^n=e$. I'm asked to prove $G(n)$ is a subgroup which is okay, nothing really special about it. However, I'm also asked to prove that given any prime $p$, it is true that $|G(p)|^2 \ge |G(p^2)|$, where the bars help denote the number of elements in each group. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9):

Consider the sequence of maps
$$G(p)\xrightarrow{g\mapsto g}G(p^2)\xrightarrow{g\mapsto g^p}G(p)\ .$$
The first map is injective and its image is the kernel of the second map, thus it follows that
$$|G(p^2)/G(p)|\le|G(p)|,$$
from which the claim follows immediately.

Comment: In keeping with the notation used by OP, I would indicate the second map as $g\mapsto g^p$. Otherwise, the answer is clear and to the point! +1

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thanks! Edited the notation to multiplicative instead of additive.

Comment: Actually, your proof shows that the condition that p be prime may be dropped. My approach was not working since it solely relied on Lagrange's theorem and some arithmetic leading nowhere. Never thought about using one of the isomorphism theorems. Thank you!

Comment: @SebastiánVargas You should be able to also do it using Lagrange's theorem and the fact that $G(p)$ is a normal subgroup of $G(p^2)$, but personally I find the proof I gave above far cleaner.